# Importing tables with multi-column foreign keys from RDBMS with ETL

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to import in a OrientDB database (version 2.1.12) some tables from a RDBMS (MySQL) schema.

For instance in MySQL schema I have a table named drug with a foreign key linked to an attribute of another table named demo, defined as follow:

```
primaryid bigint references demo(PRIMARYID) on update cascade on delete cascade
```

For this relationship I have no problems to define ETL module for importing in orientDB graph, because I use a trasformer defined as follow:

```
"transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "drug" } },
    { "edge": { "class": "drugDemo",
                "joinFieldName": "primaryid",
                "lookup": "demo.primaryid",
                "direction": "in"
            }
        }
  ],
```

that creates correctly an edge connection between demo and drug classes, using primaryid attribute as join field.

But I have also a table named indi with multi-column foreign key defined as follow:

```
foreign key (PRIMARYID, INDI_DRUG_SEQ) references drug(PRIMARYID, DRUG_SEQ)
```

In this case how can I define edge transormer in ETL module that correctly import table into a graph?

From orientDB documentation I can't find a solution for multi-columns foreign keys. I think that a possible solution is to define a new attribute as a concatenation of strings of PRIMARYID and INDI_DRUG_SEQ attributes, using a separator, but I'm not sure that it is a good solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying with this and it seems working:

```
"transformers": [
{ "vertex": { "class": "indi" } },
{ "edge": { "class": "indiDemo",
            "joinFieldName": "primaryID",
            "lookup": "demo.primaryID",
            "joinFieldName": "indi_drug_seq",
            "lookup": "demo.drug_seq",
            "direction": "in"
        }
}
 ],
```

Let me know if it works for you too.